# Исправление ошибки при запуске сервера на языке GO

Tags: golang, сервер, github, веб-сервер, opensource

Потребовалось поднять сервер который при обращении к нему захватывают запросы к некоторым портам, для этого решил использовать проект на гит-хабе(https://github.com/ArturSS7/TukTuk),
но при компиляции у меня возникла ошибка с 2 модулями backend.go и login.go. В первом у ругается на создание сессии

```
    domain = Domain
    e := echo.New()
    //pass db pointer to echo handler
    t := &Template{
        templates: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("frontend/templates/*")),
    }
    secret := []byte(RandStringBytes(20))
    e.AutoTLSManager.Cache = autocert.DirCache("/var/www/.cache")
    e.Use(session.Middleware(sessions.NewCookieStore(secret))) // ВОТ ТУТ ОШИБКА
    e.Renderer = t
    e.Use(func(h echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
        return func(c echo.Context) error {
            cc := &database.DBContext{Context: c, Db: db}
            return h(cc)
        }
    })
```

Во втором же файле компилятор ругается на переменные `c` в отрывке

```
    sess, _ := session.Get("session", c) // ТУТ
    sess.Values["username"] = login
    sess.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Path: "/",
    }
    sess.Values["username"] = login
    return sess
}

func loginRequired(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c echo.Context) error {
        if login := getLoginFromSession(c); login == "" {
            return c.Redirect(http.StatusFound, "/login")
        }
        return next(c)
    }
}

func getLoginFromSession(c echo.Context) string {
    sess, _ := session.Get("session", c) // ТУТ
    login, exists := sess.Values["username"]
    if !exists {
        return ""
    }
    return login.(string)
}
```

Сам компилятор говорит что нужно обновить библиотеку github.com/labstack/echo на github.com/labstack/echo/v4, но в данном случае всё ломается.

Текст ошибки

```
backend\backend.go:55:8: cannot use session.Middleware(sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret"))) (value of type "github.com/labstack/echo/v4".MiddlewareFunc) as type "github.com/labstack/echo".MiddlewareFunc in argument to e.Use
backend\login.go:42:36: cannot use c (variable of type "github.com/labstack/echo".Context) as type "github.com/labstack/echo/v4".Context in argument to session.Get:
        "github.com/labstack/echo".Context does not implement "github.com/labstack/echo/v4".Context (wrong type for Echo method)
                have Echo() *"github.com/labstack/echo".Echo
                want Echo() *"github.com/labstack/echo/v4".Echo
backend\login.go:61:36: cannot use c (variable of type "github.com/labstack/echo".Context) as type "github.com/labstack/echo/v4".Context in argument to session.Get:
        "github.com/labstack/echo".Context does not implement "github.com/labstack/echo/v4".Context (wrong type for Echo method)
                have Echo() *"github.com/labstack/echo".Echo
                want Echo() *"github.com/labstack/echo/v4".Echo
```

Comment: Но где же собственно текст ошибки, почему его нет в вопросе? И желательно полный, ничего не обрезайте.

Comment: исправил, и добавил текст ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать более старую версию *github.com/labstack/echo-contrib*.

Последняя версия *github.com/labstack/echo-contrib*, которая использует
*github.com/labstack/echo* (не */v4*), это *0.5.2* (важно! без лидирующей буквы *v*)

исправил в *go.mod*

```
github.com/labstack/echo-contrib 0.5.2
```

```
$ go mod tidy
```

получил

```
github.com/labstack/echo-contrib v0.0.0-20180222075343-7d9d9632a4aa
```

```
$ go build
```

ok-ob

Comment: а вы пробовали запустить данный проект, просто сейчас у меня ошибка при запуске 
`2023/08/09 13:57:27 Unable to read client secret file: open emailalert/credentials.json: no such file or directory
Connected
⇨ https server started on [::]:1234
⇨ http server started on 127.0.0.1:5555
{"time":"2023-08-09T13:57:27.19896073+05:00","level":"FATAL","prefix":"echo","file":"http.go","line":"41","message":"listen tcp :80: bind: permission denied"}
`

Comment: Нет. Судя по сообщению вам не хватает прав, чтобы забиндиться на 80 порт. Можно попробовать `su ./TukTuk'. Но стремно запускать сервер с правами root.